# Which song is featured in this Bleach scene?

Tags: music, bleach

In [Bleach episode 8, part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqBoX5nZBFc#t=1m52s), the song plays a few seconds from 1:52 onwards. Which song from the soundtrack is it?

Answer (score 1):

I had a listen to the OST for *Season 1* and the only song this sounds like is [Catch-22](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=48QHhyBq8kw). The quality difference is noticeable but some distinct sounds match. Unless my ears are deceiving me, ~[2:28](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=YqBoX5nZBFc#t=149) in *episode 8*  matches ~[1:45](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48QHhyBq8kw&feature=youtu.be&t=1m45s) of the song.

Comment: Yes, Catch 22 plays near 2:20. But I meant the song that played 1:52 to 2:20, that accompanies the soft-spoken, grave dialog between the two.

Comment: @aitchnyu I went through the entire OST and nothing matched that part. I assume it might have just been some 'fill in' audio or a bit from another track. Why I also linked to ~2:28 was that most of that part wasn't very clear either. I will have another listen later to see if I missed something providing someone else doesn't post an answer by then.

Comment: @iKlsR it's most likely the same song but a small clip of it slightly edited, the same happens in Black Cat when Saya goes after Predaghoul, when she's walking down the halls of the ship a roughly 5 second clip from one of the tracks from the OST is taken out with one of the audio layers removed, unfortunately the only way to get that audio is to record it from the anime and edit it to retain the original quality

Comment: @Memor-X I went through the OST again and I agree. I could find nothing sounding like that or so subtle either so that is probably what happened.